# Unable to change background color of form field in Acrobat

Tags: adobe, acrobat

For some reason I can't change the background color of a text field in Acrobat. Never had this problem before. When background is "no color" it turns any text behind it grey.

[image]

And when I change the fill color it just turns white. In the image below the background color of the field is red.

[image]

Comment: Check the settings for form fields; it could be that you have a "hover color" active.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!